# Does new Date().getTime() return the same value as strtotime("now")?

Tags: javascript, php, timestamp

I'm sending an array via ajax containing lots of javascript timestamps. However, when I convert them into DATETIME using PHP, I end up with the year  46085.

Why is this?

Javascript method:

```
 var timestamp = [new Date().getTime();]
```

PHP method

```
var timestamp = strtotime("now");
```

Comment: JavaScript works with milliseconds. Did you take that into account?

Comment: That's why it's a good idea to read documentation, isn't it?

Comment: Don't believe anything not from your own server! and doubt it even if it is.